# How to have a django model Textfield contain variables

Tags: django, python-3.x

so assume there is a model A and Django template `template.html` and there's a variable `x` which will be rendered to the template

```
class A (models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
```

Now how can I create an object through django admin which will have to use the variable `x` which will be later rendered to the django template.

django template will look like below

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>{{ a.description }}</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

object `a` and `x` is rendered to the template. Description may look like `This is the description with value of x equal to <value_of_x>`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is `x`? Where is it used or how is it stored? What do mean by "how can I create an object in django admin which will have to use x", what object?

Comment: What I meant was, can we use {{ x }} while filling the description field in admin panel, so that it'll reflect in the template (so `<div>{{ a.description }}</div>` this would have value of x which is passed on to the template from views)

Comment: You'll have to build this yourself, create a parser to parse your `description` (in your view) before passing it back to the template. That's not something that's built-in, you have to build it yourself.

Comment: This sounds a bit suspicious. Why do you want the end user to be able to control templating? This could easily turn into a security and caching nightmare if not done properly, so i wonder if there's something else, hopefully simpler, that you're actually trying to achieve

Comment: Actually, my team wants me to have a feature where admin user could change the description and also use the variables. For example: To send a donation email with the description which uses his last payment amount.